# How can I change active Bootstrap tab style to underline?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, underline, bootstrap-tabs

**Bootstrap nav tab how to change active tab to underline?**
This is my code.

```js
// Bootstrap Handles The Javascript
```

```css
// Add css to underline the active tab
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you simply want the border to continue through? Do you want text underline? Please revise to add detail.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```js
// Tabs
var triggerTabList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".nav-tabs>button")
);
triggerTabList.forEach(function (triggerEl) {
    var tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl);

    triggerEl.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".nav-tabs>button").forEach(
            (button) =>
                (button.style.cssText = `
            background-color: #fff;
            color: rgb(245, 158 ,11);
            transition: background-color .5s;
            `)
        );

        document.querySelectorAll(".nav-tabs>button.active").forEach(
            (button) =>
                (button.style.cssText = ` 
          cursor: default;
          background-color: #fff;
          font-weight: bold;
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(245, 158 ,11);
          color: rgb(245, 158 ,11);
          transition: all .5s;`)
        );
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs>button.active,
.nav-tabs>button.active:hover,
.nav-tabs>button.active:focus {
  color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1976d2;
}

.nav-tabs>button {
  transition: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.nav-tabs>button:hover {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /* font-size: initial; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed the problem

Comment: Looks better, but there's movement in the text and the unselected tabs don't have the thin gray underline. Details matter.